# Rotating MDRotatingPieChart changes x/y position instead of angle

Tags: ios, swift, math, geometry, pie-chart

[image: Screenshot of MDRotatingPieChart]

I want to have a rotating piechart in my iOS application. I've found MDRotatingPieChart control that seems to do most of what I need. But when I put it into non-`(0,0)` origin and start to drag, it changes the X and Y position of the piechart as well. It shouldn't do this. Can someone help me out here?

Here is the code that seems relevant

```
pieChart = MDRotatingPieChart(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: view.frame.width + 30 , height: view.frame.width + 30 ))
```

and inside `MDRotatingPieChart`:

```
override func continueTracking(_ touch: UITouch, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    hasBeenDraged = true
    let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
    let deltaX = currentPoint.x - pieChartCenter.x - 15
    let deltaY = currentPoint.y - pieChartCenter.y - 15
    let ang = atan2(deltaY,deltaX);
    let angleDifference = delta - ang
    self.transform = self.transform.rotated(by: -angleDifference)
    let savedTransform = slicesArray[0].labelObj?.transform
    let savedTransformCenter = labelCenter.transform
    for slice in slicesArray  {
        if(slice.labelObj != nil)  {
            slice.labelObj?.transform = savedTransform!.rotated(by: angleDifference)
        }
    }
    labelCenter.transform = savedTransformCenter.rotated(by: angleDifference)
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  When the pie chart rotates, its x and y change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it looks like you should use MDRotatingPieChart.swift from [MDRotatingPieChart-Example folder](https://github.com/maxday/MDRotatingPieChart/tree/master/MDRotatingPieChart-Example) as it is much more modern. Still it contains the bug you described and the source of the bug seems to be that the original developer doesn't know the difference between `frame` and `bounds` which are according to the [`UIView` doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview):

> The geometry of each view is defined by its `frame` and `bounds` properties. The `frame` property defines the origin and dimensions of the view in the coordinate system of its superview. The `bounds` property defines the internal dimensions of the view as it sees them and is used almost exclusively in custom drawing code.

So to fix the issue you can find the following [line in createSlice](https://github.com/maxday/MDRotatingPieChart/blob/master/MDRotatingPieChart-Example/MDRotatingPieChart/MDRotatingPieChart.swift#L505)

```
    mask.frame = self.frame
```

and replace it with

```
    mask.frame = self.bounds
```

**P.S.** Your code features a line

```
pieChart = MDRotatingPieChart(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: view.frame.width + 30 , height: view.frame.width + 30 ))
```

which is suspicious. You almost never want either `width` or `height` of a child to be more than corresponding parent's dimension. You probably want

```
pieChart = MDRotatingPieChart(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 30,
             width: view.frame.width - 30 , height: view.frame.width - 30 ))
```

or even (if you want symmetrical margins in both X and Y)

```
pieChart = MDRotatingPieChart(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, 
               width: view.frame.width - 2*30 , height: view.frame.width - 2*30 ))
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks a Lot. You are my saviour.

Comment: @varun, you are welcome. As a side-note I'd like to point that I think that if your question was originally at least as good as after my edit, you might have not needed to start the bounty. Good question is a major step to a good answer! (It is still far from perfect but much better, for example it still lacks [MCVE] but at least explicitly points to the fact that you use a 3rd party control and that the problem might be inside that control.)